# If groups $G$ and $H$ act on $X$, does $G\times H$ act on $X$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups, direct-product

Suppose two groups $G$ and $H$ act on a set $X$.

> What is the group action of $G\times H$ on $X$?

From the actions there a homomorphisms $\varphi\colon G\to S_X$ and $\psi\colon H\to S_X$. So this induces a homomorphism from the coproduct $\Phi\colon G\times H\to S_X$, so there should be an action.

Identifying $G$ and $H$ with the subgroups $\{(g,e):g\in G\}$ and $\{(e,h):h\in H\}$ by the inclusions into the coproduct, it seems $(g,e)$ should act as $g$, and $(e,h)$ should act as $h$, as $\Phi(g,e)=\varphi(g)$ and $\Phi(e,h)=\psi(h)$. Since $(g,h)=(g,e)(e,h)$, it seems like $(g,h)$ should act as $g\cdot (h\cdot x)$.

My concern was that 
$$
((g_1,h_1)(g_2,h_2))\cdot x=(g_1g_2,h_1h_2)\cdot x=g_1g_2\cdot(h_1h_2\cdot x)
$$
but
$$
(g_1,h_2)\cdot((g_2,h_2)\cdot x)=g_1\cdot(h_1\cdot(g_2\cdot (h_2\cdot x))
$$

If the actions of $G$ and $H$ "commute," this seems like it would be okay, since
$$
\psi(h)\varphi(g)=\Phi(e,h)\Phi(g,e)=\Phi((e,h)(g,e))=\Phi(g,h)=\Phi((g,e)(e,h))=\varphi(g)\psi(h)
$$

but this makes it seem like any two group actions on $X$ commute, which doesn't sound like it should be true. Have I made an error somewhere?

**Edit:** I made a mistake and used the incorrect coproduct. But it seems like there is at least an action if the actions of $G$ and $H$ commute.

**Motivation:** I have $G$ and $H$ acting on a ring $X$, and I'm looking at the fixed points $X^{G\times H}$, but I'm not sure what the action of $G\times H$ should be.

Comment: The coproduct in the category of abelian groups is the direct sum--which is the same as the direct product in the case of finitely many summands.  The coproduct in the category of groups is the free product.  So your definition of the coproduct assumes that $G$ and $H$ are abelian.

Comment: @Eric Oh shoot, thanks. I'll have to rework this.

Comment: You've actually shown that commutation of the actions is necessary and sufficient to make $(g,h).x = g.(h.x)$ a group action.  You've noticed sufficiency, for necessity just specialize to the case $g_1=1$, $h_2=1$, and such that the actions of $g_2$ and $h_1$ do not commute.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy That's a good point, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have a set $X$ equipped with actions coming from two different groups:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \alpha:G_1\to{\rm Sym}(X) \\ \beta:G_2\to {\rm Sym}(X) \end{array} $$

Denote $\ker\alpha=K_1$ and $\ker\beta=K_2$. Automatically we get induced *faithful* actions

$$\overline{\alpha}:G_1/K_1\to{\rm Sym}(X) \\ \overline{\beta}:G_1/K_1\to{\rm Sym}(X) $$

At this juncture we can define the group $H=\overline{\alpha}(G_1/K_1)\cap \overline{\beta}(G_2/K_2)$. Since $\overline{\alpha}$ and $\overline{\beta}$ are injective by construction, we have maps $\overline{\alpha}^{-1}:H\to G_1/K_1$ and $\overline{\beta}^{-1}:H\to G_2/K_2$. Then our two actions induce an action of the amalgamated free product $G_1/K_1 *_H G_2/K_2$. We could have just said we get an action of the free product $G_1*G_2$, but the elements of $K_1$ and $K_2$ inside act trivially, and then the images of $h\in H$ in $G_1/K_1$ act the same as their images in $G_2/K_2$ so we might as well encode that fact too.

If $[\alpha(G_1),\beta(G_2)]=1$ within ${\rm Sym}(X)$ then we can say there is an induced action of $G_1\times G_2$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no group action unless the actions of $G$ and $H$ commute, in which case there is a unique natural action. The key point is *associativity* in the definition/characterization of "action", namely, that
$$
(g_1\times h_1)\cdot \Big((g_2\times h_2)\cdot x\Big)
\;=\; 
(g_1g_2\times h_1h_2)\cdot x
$$
When the actions commute, defining $(g\times h)\cdot x= g\cdot(h\cdot x)$ and or $h\cdot (g\cdot x)$ gives associativity.

When the actions do not commute, that means for some $g$ and $h$ and $x$ we have $g\cdot (h\cdot x)\not=h\cdot (g\cdot x)$. This would contravene associativity, because, while $(g\times 1)$ and $(1\times h)$ commute in $G\times H$,
$$
g\cdot (h\cdot x)\;=\; (g\times 1)\cdot \Big((1\times h)(x)\Big)
\;=\; 
\Big((g\times 1)(1\times h)\Big)(x)
\;=\;
\Big((1\times h)(g\times 1)\Big)(x)
\;=\; \ldots \;=\; h\cdot(g\cdot x)
$$
contradiction.

(The uniqueness is easy once we say clearly what the requirement is.)