# Group action of direct product group $G \times H$ when groups $G$ and $H$ do not commute

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, direct-product

I'm studying direct product groups actions. Usually, for a group $G \times H$ acting on a set $X$ one takes the group action $\cdot_{G \times H}$ to be the natural $(g \times h)(x) = g \cdot_G (h \cdot_H x)$ for a $(g,h) \in G \times H$ and $x \in X$. However, it turns out that this is well defined **only** if actions of $G$ and $H$ commute. See the question on [If groups $G$ and $H$ act on $X$, does $G \times H$ act on $X$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403537/if-groups-g-and-h-act-on-x-does-g-times-h-act-on-x). Hence, I'm interested in situations wherein that hypothesis doesn't hold, *i.e.*, actions of $G$ and $H$ do **not** commute.

Assume groups $G$ and $H$ act on set $X$ and that they **do not commute**.

What could be a **non-natural** action of direct product group $G \times H$ on $X$ (other than the trivial one)?
(Note that the action is **not** the natural $(g \times h) \cdot x = g \cdot (h \cdot x)$ since $G$ and $H$ do not commute which was shown to be sufficient and necessary in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403537/if-groups-g-and-h-act-on-x-does-g-times-h-act-on-x).)

Specifically, how could one combine the results of group actions of the elements $g$ and $h$? (The natural action uses composition).

Thank you

Comment: A "non-natural" action is the trivial one. Your question is unclear. You want an action which is both "non-natural" and "combines  the results of group actions of the elements $g$
 and $h$". This seems contradictory. Please clarify your post.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thx. Something more interesting, please.

Comment: There are the slightly-less-trivial actions where you completely ignore $h$ and just use the action of $G$, or vice versa, but it sounds like that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @pastebee Thx. Correct, something that would combine/use the actions of $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Please provide context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ and $H$ act on $X$ and their actions don't commute, then there's *no reason to expect* $G \times H$ to act on $X$. Here's an explicit counterexample, followed by a more abstract view that lets you guess the correct answer (so that you can focus on looking for a counterexample rather than a proof).

First, let $G = \mathbb{Z}/2 = \langle \sigma | \sigma^2 \rangle$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}/3 = \langle \tau \mid \tau^3 \rangle$. Then both of these groups act on $X = \{1,2,3\}$, by sending $\sigma$ to the permutation $(1 \ 2)$ and $\tau$ to the permutation $(1 \ 2 \ 3)$. I'll let you check that these really define actions.

Now we ask about $G \times H = \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3$. It's not hard to check that $G \times H$ has no faithful action on $X$, since $\text{Aut}_X = \mathfrak{S}_3$ (the symmetric group on $3$ letters) has $6$ elements. So $G \times H$ surely doesn't act [faithfully](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaithfulGroupAction.html). Indeed, by comparing the subgroups of $\mathfrak{S}_3$ to the quotients of $G \times H$ (using the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(groups))
one can show that *the only* actions${}^1$ of $G \times H$ on $X$ in this case are $(g,h) \cdot x = g \cdot x$ or $(g,h) \cdot x = h \cdot x$! We *must* simply ignore one of the factors! So there is no action of $G \times H$ that uses the information from both $G$ and $H$.

---

Now, how could we have seen this coming? An action of $G$ on $X$ can similarly be described as a group homomorphism $G \to \text{Aut}_X$. So your question can be rephrased as "given two homomorphisms $G \to \text{Aut}_X$ and $H \to \text{Aut}_X$ whose images don't commute in $\text{Aut}_X$, is there a group homomorphism $G \times H \to \text{Aut}_X$.

This should ring as false to you. After all, "$G \times H$" is the free way to glue $G$ and $H$ together assuming they commute! In general it's very hard to control maps *out* of $G \times H$ (here knowing some [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) can also help guide your intuition). So our hope is to search for a counterexample.

The easiest thing to do is to take these maps $G \to \text{Aut}_X$ and $H \to \text{Aut}_X$ to be inclusions, so that we actually have subgroups $G \leq \text{Aut}_X$ and $H \leq \text{Aut}_X$. Then the dream is to find a group $\text{Aut}_X$ with two subgroups $G$ and $H$ (which don't commute in $\text{Aut}_X$) so that $G \times H$ has no interesting homomorphisms into $\text{Aut}_X$. From doing lots of these kinds of problems, I knew that $G = \mathbb{Z}/2$, $H = \mathbb{Z}/3$, and $\text{Aut}_X = \mathfrak{S}_3 = \text{Aut}_{\{1,2,3\}}$ would work. However, this is also one of the first examples you might think to try, since $\mathfrak{S}_3$ is the smallest nonabelian group! So it's the first place a counterexample *could possibly be*.

---

As a last aside, I'll say that you *can* "fix this". Instead of working with the *product* $G \times H$, you could work with the *coproduct* (also sometimes called the [*free product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product)) $G \ast H$. This is the construction that glues two groups together if we *don't* assume that their images commute! Indeed, it's defined by the property that "for any two homomorphisms $\varphi: G \to K$ and $\psi: H \to K$, there is a unique homomorphism $\varphi \ast \psi : G \ast H \to K$ which "glues $\varphi$ and $\psi$ together".

In this way, if $G$ and $H$ act on $X$ (that is, if we have homomorphisms $G \to \text{Aut}_X$ and $H \to \text{Aut}_X$) then this property *guarantees* we have a homomorphism $G \ast H \to \text{Aut}_X$ extending the previous homomorphisms. That is, it guarantees an interesting action of $G \ast H$ on $X$ in way that uses the information of the $G$ and $H$ actions.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

---

${}^1$: This is a slight fib. We can also have actions like $(g,h) \cdot x = g^{-1} \cdot x$, but these won't exist for other choices of $G$ and $H$, and also won't solve your problem.

Comment: The question has no context. It shouldn't be given an answer until it does.

Comment: This is a high quality answer though, hence no downvote.

Comment: I guess reasonable minds can differ on the amount of context needed for a question. It's very easy for me to picture somebody reading the linked question, wondering if the hypotheses can be weakened, and asking this question. And for a beginner in group theory, I think this question would be very difficult, where I'm not sure what attempts they could show besides what's already in the question.

Comment: That's fair enough, @HallaSurvivor.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Could you please explain what you meant in '"$G \times H$" is the free way to glue $G$ and $H$ together assuming they commute!' I haven't seen the direct product to **depend** on $G$ and $H$ having to commute.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Could you please elaborate on "Indeed, by comparing the subgroups of $\mathfrak{S}_3$ to the quotients of $G \times H$ using the first isomorphism theorem one can show that the only actions of $G \times H$ on $X$ in this case are $(g,h) \cdot x = g \cdot x$ or $(g,h) \cdot x = h \cdot x$!" Thanx

Comment: I mean that $G \leq G \times H$ and $H \leq G \times H$, so that we can say that $G \times H$ comes from "gluing $G$ and $H$ together". But inside $G \times H$, $G$ and $H$ commute! Indeed $(g,1_H) \cdot (1_G, h) = (1_G, h) \cdot (g, 1_H)$. So certainly $G \times H$ is "a way of gluing $G$ and $H$ together so that they commute". As for the "free" way to do this, the explanation depends on some category theory to make precise. 1/2

Comment: Basically, if $\phi : G \to K$ and $\psi : H \to k$ are two group homomorphisms where $\text{im}(\phi)$ and $\text{im}(\psi)$ commute (so that we can think of $K$ as being "a way to glue $G$ and $H$ together so they commute") then there is a unique $\phi \times \psi : G \times H \to K$ (given by sending $(g,h) \mapsto \phi(g) \times \psi(h)$). This is the sense in which $G \times H$ is the "free" such construction. 2/2

Comment: As for the first isomorphism theorem, we know $G \times H \cong \mathbb{Z}/6$. So an action of $G \times H$ on a set with three elements is a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/6 \to \mathfrak{S}_3$. Now the image of this hom is a subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_3$. But by the first isomorphism theorem the image of this hom is _also_ a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}/6$! So in order to understand this homomorphism, we need to understand which groups are both a subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_3$ and a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}/6$, as these are the only possible images, and thus the possible actions.

Comment: It's not hard to check that the only groups that fit the bill are $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3$, which are the $G$ and $H$ we started with! Using this you can show that the only possible actions of $G \times H$ are to ignore (read: quotient out) either $G$ or $H$

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Wow! Thank you very very much! I'll need some time to digest this ;)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I know that the subgroups of $\mathfrak{S}_3$ are $\{\{e\}, \mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/3, \mathfrak{S}_3\}$. The action corresponding to $\{e\}$ is trivial, but what about $\mathfrak{S}_3$? Its disqualification seems somehow to be related to the requirement that $G$ and $H$ do not commute, but I don't see how. Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/6 = \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3$ is _not_ isomorphic to $\mathfrak{S}_3$. For instance, one is abelian and the other isn't. This also makes the relationship to $G$ and $H$ commuting more clear, since they do in $\mathbb{Z}/6$ and they don't in $\mathfrak{S}_3$.